# how to remove en element from an array by using where(..).Select(..) in c#?

Tags: c#

In c#, I am getting report parameters of a report (Microsoft Reporting Services) by using:

```
public ItemParameter[] GetServerReportParameterInfo(string rdlName)
        {
            //var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            var reportPath = "/" + AppUtil.GetAppSettingValueByKey(Constants.ReportFolder) + "/" + rdlName.RemoveEnd(4);
            const bool forRendering = false;
            ItemParameter[] parametersItems;
            var trustedUserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();

            var rs = new ReportingService2010SoapClient("ReportingService2010Soap");
            if (rs.ClientCredentials != null)
                rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            rs.GetItemParameters(trustedUserHeader, reportPath, null, forRendering, null, null, out parametersItems);

            return parametersItems;
        }


...
ItemParameters[] parameterCollection = GetServerReportParameterInfo(rdl);
```

It is returning the parameters correctly to me, however, there are some parameters whose .prompt property is null. I need to remove them from parameterCollection. I need a code like below, but could not find the correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

```
parameterCollection = parameterCollection.Where(o=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Prompt)).Select(o=>o);
```

Comment: Can't you use RemoveAll(Predicate) to remove all that matches the predicate?

Comment: Since array's are immutable (you cannot just remove an item), you'd need to convert it to a list, then remove the item and finally back to an array. Try this: `var foos = new List<ItemParameters>(parameterCollection); foos.RemoveAll(o => string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Prompt)); parameterCollection = foos.ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq methods do not allow to modify collection/sequence (whether it is an array, list or any other collection).

You can create new filtered collection (which looks like an option in your case as you re-assigning collection):

```
parameterCollection = parameterCollection
   .Where(o=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Prompt)) // filter
   .ToArray(); // convert to new array
```

If you must use `.Select` you can add no-op select as in your question `.Selsect(x=>x)`, but it does not give any benefits.